# Using std::unique_ptr for managing COM objects

Tags: c++, c++11, com, smart-pointers

I'm trying to use smart pointers to hold COM objects in my class while avoiding ComPtr. Is it possible to use unique_ptr for this purpose?

I'm quite new to smart pointers and so far I'm a bit confused. Please consider the following simplified code:

```
class Texture
{
private:
    struct ComDeleter
    {
        operator() (IUnknown* p)
        {
            p.Release();
            delete p;
        }
    }

    ID3D11Texture* m_dumbTexture;
    std::unique_ptr<ID3D11Texture, ComDeleter> m_smartTexture;

public:
    ID3D11Texture* getDumbTexture() const { return m_dumbTexture; }
    ID3D11Texture* getSmartTexture() const { return m_smartTexture.get(); } // what to return here?
}

Texture::Texture() :
    dumbTexture  (NULL),
    smartTexture (nullptr)
{
}

Texture::init()
{
    D3DX11CreateTexture(&m_dumbTexture);
    D3DX11CreateTexture(&m_smartTexture.get());  // error: '&' requires r-value
}
```

So my problems are: what should the getter return (raw pointer or unique_ptr instance) and how can I pass the unique_ptr to function which creates the resource?

Comment: This falls into the re-inventing the wheel category. Use ComPtr and move on.

Comment: `p.Release(); delete p;` is wrong:  COM objects destroy themselves on the last `Release()`.

Comment: So no `delete p` necessary? Looks like I've been reading some wrong tutorials.

Comment: `delete p` is *very* wrong. What guarantee do you have that the COM object was allocated with C++'s `new`, and out of the same heap that your C++ library sets up for you? (hint: definitely not the case for DX objects). A major reason why COM objects manage their own lifetimes is because they are the only ones that know the correct way to deallocate themselves.

Comment: @PeterR Have found this question and upvoted it, I suppose one of my first thoughts were about code reuse and portability. It would make sense to want to avoid Windows specific code for those purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I'm trying to use smart pointers to hold COM objects in my class while avoiding `ComPtr`.

The solution is to use `ComPtr`.  `unique_ptr` is a poor substitute for `ComPtr` if you're working with COM objects.

`ComPtr` provides specialized functionality for working with COM objects and `IUnknown`.  For example, it has built in support for safe interface querying (via the `As` member function).  It is also usable with out parameters, which are common in COM (via the `GetAddressOf` functions).

Comment: So a) is it worth it to include the whole atlbase for a single smart pointer? b) As above: what should be returned by a getter (raw pointer or CComPtr instance? c) how can I release and recreate a resource held by ComPtr member (I'm getting `'ATL::_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr<T>::Release' : cannot access private member declared in class 'ATL::_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr<T>'` when trying to `m_comptr->Release(); CreateResource(&m_comptr);`.

Comment: [a] Sure.  Or use the newer `ComPtr` in `<wrl/client.h>`.  [b] It depends on the use case and exactly how callers are likely to use objects of the type.  Start with `ComPtr<T>`.  [c] You cannot call `Release` directly, and you shouldn't:  Let the `ComPtr` manage calls to `AddRef` and `Release`.  Use `GetAddressOf` or `ReleaseAndGetAddressOf` for out parameters.

Comment: Ok, cool. Just one more question: can I use `std::vector<ComPtr<T>>`?

Comment: Yes, at least in recent versions of Visual C++ (certainly in Visual C++ 2013).

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to partially reinvent the wheel, you should use `intrusive_ptr`. Implement the incrementation/decrementation methods for `IUnknown` with calling `AddRef()` and `Release()` and it should work.